# The code only runs correctly for half and at the point of f_num=num+num_rev, here output is only num_rev not f_num

Tags: python

I have an assignment to take a number from user, reverse it and add to user given number, and then check if the sum is a palindrome.

I have written the code but I am stuck at 5. First of all `f_num=num+num_rev` is not working and answer for `f_num` is `321`, which is the `num_rev` when the given input is `123`. The addition is not working and after that nothing works correctly.

```
while True:
    while True:
        try:
            num = int(input('\nEnter number:'))
        except ValueError:
            print("\nPlease enter only number")
        num_rev = 0
        while num > 0:
            dig = num %10
            num_rev = (num_rev *10) + dig
            num = num //10
        print("\nThe reverse of given number is {}.".format(num_rev))
        f_num=num+num_rev
        print("\nAfter adding the reverse number in given number,the sum is {}.".format(f_num))
        a_num_rev=0
        while f_num > 0:
            dig = f_num % 10
            a_num_rev = (a_num_rev *10) + dig
            f_num = f_num //10
        if f_num==a_num_rev:
            print("\nThe number {} is palindrome.".format(f_num))
            break
        else:
            print("\nThe number {} is not palindrome.".format(f_num))

    while True:
        Repeat=input("\nDo you want to repeat?\n\nYes or No:")
        Repeat=Repeat.lower()
        if Repeat not in ["yes","y","no","n"]:
            print("\nPlease select correct option")
        else:
            break

    if Repeat in ["yes","y"]:
        continue
    else:
        if Repeat in ["no","n"]:
            print("\n-----Thank you for using-----")
            input()
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your procedure to reverse the number you got from the user destroys the original value, so when you try to add the original and reversed values you end up with only the reversed value as your sum (the original is zero).

To make the code work, you need to keep a variable with the original value of `num` that you can use later. A line like `num_orig = num` would be enough. Then use that variable when you do the addition: `f_num = num_orig + num_rev`. Or perhaps you could rename some things and do the destructive modification on the extra variable while `num` remains the original value.

You'll also have a similar issue when you check `f_num` to see if it is equal to its own reverse. When you're computing `a_num_rev`, you destroy `f_num` (turning it into zero).